# Drawing a graph from an array of double values in Java?

Tags: java, graph, decimal, draw, diagram

I have an array of parsed double values from a csv file (a lot of them) and I would like to create some kind of a graphical graph/diagram prensentation. Is there any API designed for this? or is there some other simple way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at JFreeChart. It's pretty easy to set up.
http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/